# How to send event value on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I can check category, action, and label on Google Analytics.

However, I can't seem to check the value so I am assuming the event value is not sent.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'ad',
    eventAction: 'duration',
    eventLabel: 'ad label',
    eventValue: 20
});
```

Let me know if I am doing things wrong or any solution. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by check the value?

Comment: @DaImTo I can't check the eventValue on Google Analytics. When I check "Real Time" > "Events", I am only able to see "event category" and "event action", not "event value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real time reports dont support the event value metric.  You can see this in the [Dimensions and metrics repport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/)

You need to wait and check the behavior report.

Comment: Thank you! It showed up in "Behavior" > "Events" after some time.

Comment: it takes 24 to 48 hours for data to finish processing.